# Set default title for Wordpress Custom Post Types?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress custom post type "Featured Book", which uses a subtitle to specify title of the book. Eg: "Featured Book: The Hunger Games"

Is it possible to automatically set the title of the post as "Featured Book" ?

I found this code through Googling but it does not work (Wordpress backend returns a blank page/white screen of death)

Is there some syntax error in the code, or is this just not possible?

```
function add_custom_title( $data, $postarr ) {
  if($data['post_type'] == 'featured-book') {
    if(empty($data['post_title'])) {
      $data['post_title'] = 'Featured Book';
    }
  }
  return $data;
}
add_filters('wp_insert_post_data', 'add_custom_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Does this answer help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83583

Answer (score 3):

You've got a typo:

`add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'add_custom_title', 10, 2 );`

Answer (score 1):

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'add_custom_title', 10, 2 );
does this funtion hook fires on publish post or also on post update
I have similar script to insert post title on publish post but my problem is it also execute this function on update post. how to hook funtion only run on post publish not on update

My code

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 2 );  
function modify_post_title( $data , $postarr ) {

// Check for the custom post type and it's status
// We only need to modify it when it's going to be published

$posts_status = ['publish'];
if( $data['post_type'] == 'matrimony' && in_array($data['post_status'], $posts_status)) {

    $count_posts = wp_count_posts('matrimony');
    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
    $pending_posts = $count_posts->pending;
    if ($published_posts == 0) {
        if ($pending_posts == 0) {
            $data['post_title'] = 'ACMB' . '-1';
            $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title($data['post_title']);
        }
        else{
            // Get the most recent post
            $newposts = array(
                'numberposts' => 1,
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post_type' => 'matrimony',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );

            $last_post = wp_get_recent_posts($newposts);
            $last__post_title = $last_post['0']['post_title'];
            $number = preg_split('/[^[:alnum:]]+/', $last__post_title);
            $number = $number[1] + 1;

            // Save the title.
            $data['post_title'] = 'ACMB' . '-' . $number;
            $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title($data['post_title']);
        }
    } 
    else {

    // Get the most recent post
    $newposts = array(
                'numberposts' => 1,
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post_type' => 'matrimony',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );

    $last_post = wp_get_recent_posts($newposts);
    $last__post_title = $last_post['0']['post_title'];
    $number = preg_split('/[^[:alnum:]]+/', $last__post_title);
    $number = $number[1] + 1;

    // Save the title.
    $data['post_title'] = 'ACMB' . '-' . $number;
    $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title($data['post_title']);


}
}
return $data;
}
```