# Hook pre create Post

Tags: wordpress

Is there one way to hook when someone enters on "Create Post Page" (Not update post page) and pre-fill title and body fields?

Something like:

```
add_filter( 'WP_FILTER_ENTERS_CREATE_POST_PAGE', 'my_function_callback' )

function my_function_callback() {

    # dummy title
    $title     = 'My Post Tile';

    # dummy post content
    $post_body = '<p>Hi it is post body</p>';

    # set editor content
    wp_editor( $postBody, 'my_editor_id'); // not sure

    # set post title
    ???????

}
```

Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default title for Wordpress Custom Post Types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254827/set-default-title-for-wordpress-custom-post-types)

Comment: I want fill fields (title and content) when wp-admin/post-new.php load not after user click in submit button to post..

Answer (score 3):

After a search in Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference i found "default_content" and "default_title" filters that are exactly that i looking for!

```
# filter content
add_filter( 'default_content', 'default_editor_content', 10, 2 );

# filter content function callback
function default_editor_content( $content, $post ){
    $content = "<p><strong>Heloo!!</strong> I am custom content</p>";

    return $content;
}

# filter title
add_filter( 'default_title', 'default_title_value', 10, 2 );

# filter title function callback
function default_title_value( $title, $post ){
    $title = "Custom post Title here";

    return $title;
}
```

after this... when open wp-admin/post-new.php the title input field and editor content appears filled with default values.